# Mac ローカルの WordPress での 画像アップエラー

Tags: macos

Mac OSX Yosemite のローカルに WordPress を置いてテストしてます。
「サイト」フォルダのサブフォルダにバーチャルホストを設定してやってます。
それで WordPress のメディアライブラリで画像をアップロードする時なんですが、以下のエラーが出ます

```
ディレクトリ wp-content/uploads/2015/02 を作成できませんでした。この親ディレクトリのアクセス権はサーバーによる書き込みを許可していますか ?
```

先日、Macを移行しまして旧Macの方ではエラーが出てなかったんですが、新Macに移行してから出るようになりました。
パーミッションは新旧同じになってると思います。
所有者の問題なのかと思い、新しくフォルダを作って WordPress もダウンロードしてきたものを置いて（旧Macでしていたのと同じように）みましたがインストールの段階で以下のように出ます。

```
wp-config.php ファイルに書き込むことができません。
```

それでもインストールすることは出来るんですが、画像アップ時にはまた同様のエラーが出ます。
旧Macで出来ていたことが新Macで出来なくなってしまった原因は何なんでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

パーミッションのエラーだと思います。
試しに、uploadsフォルダのバックアップを取った上でターミナルで該当フォルダまでアクセスして、以下のコマンドを叩くと正常にアップロードできることが確認できるかと思います。

```
$ cd /~~(サイトフォルダ)/wp-content/
$ sudo chmod -R 777 uploads/
```

バックアップを元に戻して、wordpress がインストールされているディレクトリのユーザー確認を行い、

```
$ cd /~~(サイトフォルダ)/
$ ls -la
$ sudo chown -R apache:apache (サイトフォルダ)
```

ローカルの場合はmampをお使いかもしれませんので、
　　nginx や apache などではなく、 一般ユーザーになっていたら変更しましょう。